# Required String parameter is not present with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am having trouble to post 2 parameters with RestTemplate :

- a String
- a MultipartFile

I don't think there is a problem in my controller because it's very basic. It seems that the controller doesn't received the name parameter. Could you tell me what's wrong in my code

**The controller** (the receiver)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fileupload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String fileUploadHandlerName,
                             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
{
    [...]
}
```

**The Rest client** (the sender)

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
URI uri = new URI("http://127.0.0.1:7011/xxxxxxxx/admin/fileupload");

MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
parts.add("name", "import_keys");
Resource file = new ClassPathResource("xmlFileImport/file.xml");
parts.add("file", file);

rest.postForLocation(uri, parts);
```

**The controller stackTrace**

> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
>   Required String parameter 'name' is not present

Comment: Did you try this version of postForLocation?
`public URI postForLocation(String url,
                           Object request,
                           Map<String,?> urlVariables)
                    throws RestClientException`

Comment: Can a Spring controller handle multipart requests that easily with just a handler method? You need some kind of resolver, do you have one?

Comment: @bizmark I don't need to use `Map<String,?> urlVariables` because I don't pass any variable in the URL.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you were right!! I didn't use any resolver. I just use CommonsMultipartResolver and it works. Post you comments as a answer and I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: @TheEwook I'm glad you figured it out. Check if my answer contains all the details. If not, you can add your own answer for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handling multipart requests is a complex process. It's not as simple as reading request parameters. As such, Spring requires you to declare a [`MultipartResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html) so that it can parse and handle such requests. You can do this in your `applicationContext.xml` file:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"  
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">  
    <property name="maxUploadSize">  
        <value> <YOUR_SIZE> </value>  
    </property>  
    <property name="maxInMemorySize">  
        <value> <YOUR_SIZE> </value>  
    </property>      
</bean>
```

Where [`CommonsMultipartResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html) is the implementation that parse your request and split the parts so that your controller can find the plain request parameters and the file(s) uploaded.