# RestTemplate required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I have a Spring controller which is defined like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload")
    @ResponseBody
    public void handleFileUpload2(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
```

When I use postman, my request succeeds. When I use RestTemplate to make the request from another Spring service, I get the following error:

```
{"timestamp":1475579425804,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException","message":"Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present","path":"/upload"}
```

Here is how I am using RestTemplate to make the request.

```
public void uploadFile(MultipartFile file, String url) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

    body.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()));

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(body, headers); 
    restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, String.class);
}
```

I'm not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238790/required-string-parameter-is-not-present-with-spring-resttemplate) question seems to indicate that you need to add some xml to make it work properly, but since it works from Postman, I believe the actual problem is related to how I am making the rest call using RestTemplate.

If I print out the `requestEntity` I get the following:

```
<{file=[resource loaded from byte array]},{Content-Type=[multipart/form-data]}>
```

I'm using `spring-web 4.1.4.RELEASE`

Comment: HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(headers); 
restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, String.class, body);

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
body.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()));
```

try

```
body.add("file", file.getResource());
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
    </beans:bean>
```

make sure you have added this code in your spring configuration file, it may work for you.

Comment: How is this supposed to help? This XML is used to configure the receiving endpoint. But, as I mentioned the endpoint works fine when using Postman.

Answer (score 0):

It's late to answer this question. But my answer may help for people who are looking for this issue.

I got a similar issue, changing the way of reading the file solved issue for me.

```
body.add("file",new FileSystemResource(TEST_PDF_FILE_PATH));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```java
public void uploadFile(MultipartFile file, String url) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> fileMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    ContentDisposition contentDisposition =
            ContentDisposition
                    .builder("form-data")
                    .name("file")
                    .filename("stackoverflow.txt")
                    .build();

    fileMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString());
    HttpEntity<Resource> fileEntity = new HttpEntity<>(new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()), fileMap);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("file", fileEntity);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
}
```

You can use any [org.springframework.core.io.Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html).

I found this solution here: https://medium.com/red6-es/uploading-a-file-with-a-filename-with-spring-resttemplate-8ec5e7dc52ca

If you encounter `406` responses, add

```java
headers.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.ALL));
```

or something more specific.